# ASP NET MVC C# - .Model is a property but it used like a type

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having difficulties in accessing the property of my Model to View.

1. `Error: Mvc.Webviewpage<tmodel>.Model is a property but it used like a type`. In this code  `@foreach (Model.ShoutboxObject record in Model)`
2. I want to access the property of the `Model` called `ShoutboxId` in my view but there's an error.
3. Can someone help me on this. I'm just starting learning this.

Code in my Model View:

```
public class ShoutboxMainViewModel
{
    public dynamic DepartmentId { get; set; }

    // Here is the property that I want to access
    public IEnumerable<ShoutboxViewModel> ShoutboxObject { get; set; }
```

---

```
public class ShoutboxViewModel
{
    // I want to access this to my view and put into input type hidden.
    public string ShoutboxId { get; set; }      

    public dynamic ShoutboxTitle { get; set; }
```

Code in my `.cshtml` View:

```
@model IEnumerable<WMSPortal.Models.ShoutboxMainViewModel>

    @foreach (Model.ShoutboxObject record in Model) {   *//error here*

    <text>
        <input type="hidden" class="shoutbox-id" value="@record.ShoutboxId" />  
    </text>
```

Comment: `@foreach (var record in Model)` or `@foreach (WMSPortal.Models.ShoutboxMainViewModel record in Model)`

Comment: Thanks sir but still error. See below.
. 
foreach (var record in Model) 
-if I go with this, the error will transfer to "<input type="hidden" class="shoutbox-id" value="@record.ShoutboxId" />"
-Stating that "WMSPortal.Models.ShoutboxMainViewModel.ShoutboxId.get" cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead.
.

foreach (WMSPortal.Models.ShoutboxMainViewModel record in Model)
-Same error, but i think i'm accessing the "ShoutboxObject" not "ShoutboxMainViewModel"

Comment: What is it that you are wanting to access? If its `ShoutboxId` then that is a property of `ShoutboxObject` which means you need a 2nd nested loop - `@foreach (var item in record.ShoutboxObject)`

Comment: In my 1st nested loop "@foreach(WMSPortal.Models.ShoutboxMainViewModel record in Model) {" There's an error saying "foreach statement cant operate on variables of type WMSPortal.Models.ShoutboxMainViewModel because it not contains a publick definition for 'GetEnumerator' "

Comment: That is nonsense - the view in your model is `@model IEnumerable<WMSPortal.Models.ShoutboxMainViewModel>`. Your obviously making other mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need 2 loops (or use LINQ) because you have an `IEnumerable<WMSPortal.Models.ShoutboxMainViewModel>` model, and an `IEnumerable<ShoutboxViewModel>` property of that model.

```
@foreach (var viewmodel in Model) {
    @foreach (var record in viewmodel.ShoutboxObject) {
        <text>
            <input type="hidden" class="shoutbox-id" value="@record.ShoutboxId" />  
        </text>  
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sir NightOwl888 and Sir Stephen Muecke, I love you. hehehe :)

.
Follow up question please, getting an error on class ".shoutboxid", saying  "Syntax error, "," expected". Do you have an idea?

Code:
<a href="@Url.Action("DownloadAttachment", "Shoutbox", new {.shoutboxid = record.ShoutboxId})">
.
I'm just converting VBHTML to CSHTML project. Just new to this. I hope you bear with me. :)

Comment: figure it out. It should be @shoutboxid not .shoutboxid. Thank you very much guys. <3